# deleting a dictionary record in a SwiftyJSON array

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, dictionary, swifty-json

Swift 3.0 iOS 10.x SwiftyJSON

I have a SwiftyJSON array of dictionary objects that looks like this ...

```
[
  {
    "figure" : 1326,
    "account" : "Charles"
  }
  {
    "figure" : 2361,
    "account" : "James"
  }
]
```

I want to delete the record within it belonging to "James", and I came up with this code. jsonObjects contains the array you see above.

```
    var json2S = sharedDataAccess.jsonObjects

    for json2DX in 0..<json2S.count {
        var delIndex: Int? = nil
        for (jsonK, subJson) in sharedDataAccess.jsonObjects[json2DX] {

            print("json2D \(jsonK) \(subJson.stringValue) \(Name)")
            if jsonK == "account" && subJson.stringValue != Name {
                delIndex = json2DX
                print("DELETE IT  \(jsonK) \(subJson.stringValue) \(Name)")
            }
        }
        if delIndex != nil {
            json2S[0].arrayObject?.remove(at: delIndex!)
            print("DELETING IT  \(delIndex) \(Name)")
        }
    }

    sharedDataAccess.jsonObjects = JSON(json2S)
```

It works, but not quite the way I had hoped. It deletes James [assuming Name variable contains James], but it leaves me with this.

```
[
  null,
  {
    "figure" : 1326,
    "account" : "Charles"
  }
]
```

James is replaced with null... A null I don't want, how can I delete entries but not get a null or indeed just delete the null too!!

Comment: Basically do not misuse SwiftJSON as a collection type. SwiftyJSON treats `nil` values as `NSNull` like JSON does. Parse the JSON into standard collection types `Array` and `Dictionary` and change those.

Comment: Fair point; I'll recode this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, here is my answer. Posted it for good measure; not quite the same logic but followed Vadian's point.

```
var json2S = sharedDataAccess.jsonObjects

    var jsonA:[[String:Any]] = []
    for json2P in sharedDataAccess.jsonObjects {
        print("json2P \(json2P)")
        var jsonDict:[String:Any] = [:]
        var json2Save = false
        for (jsonK, subJson) in json2P {
            print("jsonK \(jsonK) \(subJson.stringValue) \(fnName)")
            jsonDict[jsonK] = subJson.stringValue
            if jsonK == "account" && subJson.stringValue == fnName {
                json2Save = true
            }
        }
        if json2Save {
            jsonA.append(jsonDict)
        }
    }

    let sharedDataAccess.jsonObjects = JSON(jsonA)
```